# Dynamic Items iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, dynamic

What is the current best practice to have dynamic items in iOS.

[image: http://puu.sh/8DTkH.png]

As you can see the headline can change in length and height dependant on the string length. I want to shift everything down according to this. It's kind of like Facebook Newsfeed.

What is the best practice? I would prefer using constraints to achieve this.

Comment: Use autolayout, which is the best tool out there to manage this type of problem

Comment: Yeah I have turned on autolayout, but doesn't seem to help - I have used "Use suggested constraints"

Comment: Just saying what everyone else has already said but you need to be using `Autolayout` to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the dynamic content in UITableViewCell, you have to do following things,

1.You should calculate the dynamic Content Size and set UITableViewCell hight

Example:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float height = [@"" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, MAXFLOAT)].height;
return height;
}
```

2.You should adjust your UI elements frame in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: Not really answered my question. I know I can do this programatically but I am looking for an easy efficient solution. I have 5 different scenarios for this happening. Also sizeWithFont is now deprecated.

Comment: @Natarajan or they could just use `Autolayout` I think I agree with the OP this doesn't actually answer what they have asked.